# Notice Undefine Offset PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, content-management-system

I'm trying to redirect a page if the admin changes the page to not visible, by changing the visible value to zero, what is wrong with my code, i keep getting the error

```
<?php
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT VISIBLE FROM  menu WHERE id=0");
 if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
 header('Location: ./unavailable.php? error=pagenotavaialbe');
 }
  else
 ?>
```

Comment: `id=0`? how is it possible?

Comment: Post your complete relevant code. Also show the line on which you're getting error with full error you're getting.

Comment: I think you can try if condition with no of rows for this purpose.

Comment: @voodoo417 user is expecting `visible = 0` kind of code. Bur he is checking `id = 0 (may be autoincrement)`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT VISIBLE FROM  menu WHERE id=0");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
 header('Location: ./unavailable.php? error=pagenotavaialbe');
 exit;
} else {
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//do your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if($result)
{ 
   if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   { 
      header('Location: ./unavailable.php? error=pagenotavaialbe'); 
   }
}
```